# Checking flat- and smoothness: enough to check on closed points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, complex-geometry

I am currently studying varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, i know some scheme theory.

- Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of varieties. If we want to show flatness, is it enough to check the condition only at the closed points of $Y$? If yes, could you give an argument, if not, could you give an example where $f$ is flat over all closed points of $Y$, but not over some non-closed point?
- Same question with $f$ smooth of relative dimension $n$, using the following characterization of smooth (Hartshorne III.10.5):

$f$ is called smooth if it is flat and for all $y \in Y$ the "algebraic closure of the fibre" $X_{\overline{y}} := X_y \times_{k(y)} \overline{k(y)}$ is regular (and equidimensional of dimension $n$). Now it must be clear what is meant by smooth "at a point" $y \in Y$.

The question originally continued after this, but i decided to split it since it became too long. Second part: [(Continued:) finiteness of étale morphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182770/continued-finiteness-of-etale-morphisms)

Thanks a lot!

PS tag "complex-geometry" is included since i'm happy to assume $k=\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes.

1. For the flatness: a module $M$ over a ring $A$ is flat if and only if for all maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $A$, $M_\mathfrak m$ is flat over $A_\mathfrak m$.
2. The smooth locus is open in $X$. If it contains all closed points of $X$, then it is equal to $X$.

Comment: Happy to see you back, QiL: I missed you!

Comment: Remarkably simple, easy to check, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @GeorgesElencwajg ! Je vois que tu es toujours aussi dévoué :).