# Finite maps and jacobian condition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-schemes

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and take $f_{1}, ..., f_{n} \in k[X_{1},..., X_{n}]$ with the jacobian condition: $\det J_{f} = 1$. Let  $A:= k[X_{1},...,X_{n}]/(f_{1},...,f_{n})$ and consider the map induced:

$$f^{*}: Spec(A) \longrightarrow Spec(k)$$

In this case, $f^{*}$ is an finite map. Indeed, the jacobian condition implies that $A$ is an artinian $k$-algebra and so $l_{k}(A) = \dim_{k} A < \infty.$

My question is the following:

Assume that $k$ is only a domain. Is $f^{*}$ an finite map?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood this correctly or if my answer works. But if you take $n=1$ and let $k$ be any non-Noetherian domain containg $\mathbb Z$ and let $f_1=X_1$. Then you should be done, no?

Comment: no, in your case, $A = k[X_{1}]/X_{1} = k$ and so finitely generated as $k$- module.

Comment: If you relax your condition to that in the definition of an étale morphism, then the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182794/501746) is no.