# Is smoothness of morhisms enough to check closed points.?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

**Question**:Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism locally of finite presentation. If $f$ is smooth at all closed points of X, then is $f$ smooth? The definition of smooth is as follow: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sophf.jpg)

This question arise when I read the proof of flat morphisms locally of finite presentation with smooth geometoric fibers are smooth in the theorem 25.2.2 of Vakil's FOAG,(http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf).

I know a related post(  [Checking flat- and smoothness: enough to check on closed points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182766/checking-flat-and-smoothness-enough-to-check-on-closed-points)). But my situation is more generally.The smooth locus $X_{sm}$ of $X$ is open in $X$ and the set of all closed points of $X$ are contained  in $X_{sm}$. But does any point of $X$ have a specialization that is a closed point of $X$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the following is true:

**Proposition.** *Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a morphism locally of finite presentation, and suppose that $X$ is quasi-compact. If $f$ is smooth at all closed points of $X$, then $f$ is smooth.*

*Proof.* The locus $X_\mathrm{sm}$ on which $f$ is smooth is open in $X$. Moreover, every point in $X$ specializes to a closed point in $X$ by the proof of [[Schwede](https://doi.org/10.1090/conm/386/07222), Prop. 4.1] since $X$ is quasi-compact. Thus, $X_\mathrm{sm} = X$. $\blacksquare$

On the other hand, if $X$ is not quasi-compact, then [[Schwede](https://doi.org/10.1090/conm/386/07222), Thm. 4.6] shows that $X$ might not have any closed points at all!

**EDIT.** The condition "$X$ is quasi-compact" can be replaced by "$X$ is locally noetherian" since every point in a locally noetherian scheme specializes to a closed point by [Stacks, [Tag 02IL](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02IL)].